# How to add other prefixes to make an animation compatible with other browsers?

Tags: css, css-animations

I made an animation using -webkit- prefix and it worked fine. This is the code:

```
.popuptext.show {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 5s;
    animation: fadeinout 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Now I want to add other prefixes to make the animation compatible with other browsers, but I'm not sure how to do it. This is my idea:

```
.popuptext.show {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 5s;
    -moz-animation: fadeinout 5s;
    -o-animation: fadeinout 5s;
    animation: fadeinout 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeinout {
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeinout {
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

As you can see I added the prefixes for Mozilla and Opera.

Comment: Which browsers are you targeting, exactly? 99% of the time, you don't need these prefixes and can stick with `@keyframes` only.

Comment: @AndyHoffman I'm just learning how to code, I read that -webkit- is supported by some browsers so I decided to make my animation compatible with others by adding other prefixes, but also want to know if the way I added them is the right way to do it in case in the future I need to add more prefixes.

Comment: You don't need to use the prefixes, because support for `@keyframes` is native. Have a look [here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_keyframes) for property support. 97.22% of all browsers natively support this without any prefixes.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Thanks! I wasn't aware of this site. It will help me a lot from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need to use different browser prefixes. First thing to do is check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) and see how well supported the css is.

If it's not supported just append the prefix as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)